# Drop element centered on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a container where I want to drop an image from a menu below but when I drop it at the main container I cannot get the proper position, it seems it is dropped randomly in the container. How can I get the item dropped centered at mouse position?

```js
var x = null;

$(function() {
  $(".piece").draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: 'clone',
    containment: '#container',
  });

  $(".piece").droppable({
    accept: ".cap",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      x = ui.helper.clone();
      x.appendTo(this);
    }
  });

  $(".cap").draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    helper: 'clone'
  });

  $("#container").droppable({
    accept: ".piece",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      x = $('<div/>');
      x.addClass('piece-div');
      x.css('top', ui.position.top);
      x.css('left', ui.position.left);

      x.draggable({
        containment: '#container',
        cursor: 'move',
      });

      x.appendTo(this);

      x.droppable({
        accept: ".cap",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          var y = $('<img />');
          y.attr('src', ui.helper.attr('src'));
          y.css('top', ui.offset.top);
          y.css('left', ui.offset.left);
          y.appendTo(this);
        }
      });
      ui.helper.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

I expect the four colored piece to be dropped centered at mouse position in the grey container but it gets dropped almost randomly. Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/littletrives/6p8grnsk/143/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might just need to adjust your settings a little.  These %'s work in the fiddle but you may need to adjust them with better CSS for your end purpose:

```
 $("#container").droppable({
    accept: ".piece",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      x = $('<div/>');
      x.addClass('piece-div');
      x.css('top', '15%');  // Change this to some %
      x.css('left','35%'); // Change this to some %

      x.draggable({
        containment: '#container',
        cursor: 'move',
      });
```